# Инициализация множества перемнных в цикле

Tags: java, инициализация

Мне нужно было инициализировать около 500 ячеек для таблицы эксель и затем заполнить их.
я сделал инициализацию через массив.

```
private void write(String PATH) {
    try {
        InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(PATH + "\\workbook.xlsx");
        Workbook wb = null;
        try {
            wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
        } catch (EncryptedDocumentException | InvalidFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(1);
        int rowCounter = 0;
        Cell[] mas = new Cell[500];
        List<Cell> cellList = new LinkedList<Cell>();
        for (int i = 0; i < getFinishFile().size(); i++) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowCounter++);
            for (int j = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
                mas[i] = row.createCell(j);
                cellList.add(mas[i]);
            }
            int j = 0;
            for (Cell c : cellList) {
                c.setCellValue(getFinishFile().get(i)[j]);
                j++;
            }
        }
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(PATH + "\\workbook.xlsx");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

а можно это сделать как-то по быстрее и по локаничней?

Comment: А для чего вам нужен этот Cell[] mas? Если вы его используете только для того, чтобы вставить в лист?

Comment: не очень понял комментарий. да я его использую только для вставки в лист. а что в таком случае не верно?

Comment: Я не понимаю, зачем он вам нужен. Почему не добавлять напрямую? Без этого массива

Comment: ну я понял что процесс записи данных в ячейку такой 1. row.createCell(j) - создаем ячейку, 2. потом добавляем в нее значение setCellValue(...])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я все правильно понял, то примерно так делается:

```
private static final LENGTH = 500

private void write(String PATH) {
    try {
        InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(PATH + "\\workbook.xlsx");
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < getFinishFile().size(); i++) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < LENGTH; j++) {
              row.createCell().setCellValue(getFinishFile().get(i)[j])
            }
        }
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(PATH + "\\workbook.xlsx");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    } catch (EncryptedDocumentException | IOException e | InvalidFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Можно еще циклы через IntStream переписать, но думаю и так норм.

Comment: спасибо. на счет IntStream  я почитаю.